# How to read a JSON object in Go without decoding it (for use in reading a large stream)

Tags: json, go, stream, decode, unmarshalling

I am reading JSON in response to an HTTP endpoint and would like to extract the contents of an array of objects which is nested inside.  The response can be large so I am trying to use a streaming approach instead of just json.Unmarshal'ing the whole thing.  The JSON looks like so:

```
{
"useless_thing_1": { /* etc */ },
"useless_thing_2": { /* etc */ },
"the_things_i_want": [
  { /* complex object I want to json.Unmarshal #1 */ },
  { /* complex object I want to json.Unmarshal #2 */ },
  { /* complex object I want to json.Unmarshal #3 */ },
  /* could be many thousands of these */
],
"useless_thing_3": { /* etc */ },
}
```

The json library provided with Go has `json.Unmarshal` which works well for complete JSON objects.  It also has `json.Decoder` which can unmarshal full objects or provide individual tokens.  I can use this tokenizer to carefully go through and extract things but the logic to do so is somewhat complex and I cannot then easily still use `json.Unmarshal` on the object after I've read it as tokens.

The json.Decoder is buffered which makes it difficult to read one object (i.e. `{ /* complex object I want to json.Unmarshal #1 */ }`) and then consume the `,` myself and make a new `json.Decoder` - because it will try to consume the comma itself.  This is the approach I tried and haven't been able to make work.

I'm looking for a better solution to this problem.  Here is the broken code when I tried to manually consume the commas:

```golang
// code here that naively looks for `"the_things_i_want": [` and
// puts the next bytes after that in `buffer`

// this is the rest of the stream starting from `{ /* complex object I want to json.Unmarshal #1 */ },`
in := io.MultiReader(buffer, res.Body) 

dec := json.NewDecoder(in)

for {

    var p MyComplexThing
    err := dec.Decode(&p)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // steal the comma from in directly - this does not work because the decoder buffer's its input
    var b1 [1]byte
    _, err = io.ReadAtLeast(in, b1[:], 1) // returns random data from later in the stream
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    switch b1[0] {
    case ',':
        // skip over it
    case ']':
        break // we're done
    default:
        panic(fmt.Errorf("Unexpected result from read %#v", b1))
    }
}
```

Comment: Fwiw https://github.com/exponent-io/jsonpath looks promising seems to be erroring reading an array nested like the above (and all the examples only show a single Unmarshal call, not multiple from an array)

Comment: Use [Decoder.Token](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Decoder.Token) to walk through the document to the point of interest.  Call [Decoder.Decode](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Decoder.Decode) unmarshal the JSON value to a Go value. Repeat as needed to slurp up all values of interest.

Comment: Thanks @CeriseLimón yes, that would work.  The drawback is it requires me to write code that understands the structure of `useless_thing_1` and `useless_thing_2` in order to navigate over them with Token() (in my actual data they are also complex).  I guess I could just count the '{' and '}' and make a little depth tracker or stack but I was hoping to avoid having to do that.

Comment: See https://play.golang.org/p/AJDhF1Vbl8D for a function that skips an arbitrary JSON value.

Comment: Nice one @CeriseLimón ! That's a good and simple solution, thanks.

Comment: A plain json.Unmarshal into an struct variable which declares just one field for "the_things_I_want" should work too: It will read all the useless stuff (of course) and do lexical analysis of it (you hav to do that too) but not unmarshal it.

Comment: @Volker yes understood, but it means the processing I have to do on the data has to wait until everything is Unmarshaled, would be best to stream it

Comment: There are three things here: 1. You have to _read_ what you want to process and no technique whatsoever can spare you this. 2. You have to _decode_ the JSON at least until the end of the part you are interested in, again no technique can spare you this. 3. You have to _unmarshal_ at least the part you are interested in, no technique can spare you this.

Comment: The only things you can get rid of: a) Do not _unmasrshal_ the part _before_ the interersting stuff. b) Do not _unmasrshal_ the part _after_ the interersting stuff. c) Do not _decode_ the part _after_ the interersting stuff. d) Do not _read_ the part _after_ the interersting stuff. Using encoding/json.Unmarshal would not do a) and not b) but it would do c) and d). These two are useless work but this might be not _much_ work. Do not conflate reading, decoding and unmarshaling into a data structure.

Comment: @Volker Sure, of course.  Just looking for the simplest way.

Comment: You can get rid of c) and d) too with encoding/json.Unmarshal by implementing Unmarshaler and doing some hacks to signal that your Unmarshaler is done. E.g. it could send the unmarshales interesting stuff on a channel which is processed concurrently to the rest of the work encoding/json.Unmarshal does or it could abort unmarshaling with a sentinel error value. This could spare you c) and d). But of course you should measure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Decoder.Token](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Decoder.Token) and [Decoder.More](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Decoder.More) to decode a JSON document as a stream.

Walk through the document with [Decoder.Token](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Decoder.Token) to the JSON value of interest. Call [Decoder.Decode](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Decoder.Decode) unmarshal the JSON value to a Go value. Repeat as needed to slurp up all values of interest.

Here's some code with commentary explaining how it works:

```
func decode(r io.Reader) error {
    d := json.NewDecoder(r)

    // We expect that the JSON document is an object.
    if err := expect(d, json.Delim('{')); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // While there are fields in the object...
    for d.More() {

        // Get field name
        t, err := d.Token()
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        // Skip value if not the field that we are looking for.
        if t != "the_things_i_want" {
            if err := skip(d); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            continue
        }

        // We expect JSON array value for the field.
        if err := expect(d, json.Delim('[')); err != nil {
            return err
        }

        // While there are more JSON array elements...
        for d.More() {

            // Unmarshal and process the array element.

            var m map[string]interface{}
            if err := d.Decode(&m); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            fmt.Printf("found %v\n", m)
        }

        // We are done decoding the array.
        return nil

    }
    return errors.New("things I want not found")
}

// skip skips the next value in the JSON document.
func skip(d *json.Decoder) error {
    n := 0
    for {
        t, err := d.Token()
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        switch t {
        case json.Delim('['), json.Delim('{'):
            n++
        case json.Delim(']'), json.Delim('}'):
            n--
        }
        if n == 0 {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

// expect returns an error if the next token in the document is not expectedT.
func expect(d *json.Decoder, expectedT interface{}) error {
    t, err := d.Token()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if t != expectedT {
        return fmt.Errorf("got token %v, want token %v", t, expectedT)
    }
    return nil
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JT7ZFyr1LIf).